# How to set an enable null url parameter in WSO2 ESB API Resource

Tags: api, wso2-esb

When I create a API resource in WSO2 ESB with the uri-template as:

```
/getbypage_xml/{usid}/{level}/{pageNum}/{lineNum}/?zzjgbm={zzjgbm}
```

thus, we plan the zzjgbm parameter is enable null, like

```
/getbypage_xml/{usid}/{level}/{pageNum}/{lineNum}
```

However, WSO2 ESB response 202 status code, means unacceptable.

Furthermore, if I use the following template

```
/getbypage_xml?usid={usid}&level={level}&pageNum={pageNum}&lineNum={lineNum}&zzjgbm={zzjgbm}
```

When I invoke

```
/getbypage_xml?usid={usid}&level={level}&pageNum={pageNum}&lineNum={lineNum}
```

or I change the order of parameters, the result is the same.

So, How do I set a uri-template enable the parameter is enable, and at once, when the parameter is existed, I can use `get-property('uri.var.zzjgbm')` to get 
the value of it.